# How to run unit tests when node_modules is in a different directory

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, unit-testing, aws-lambda

I have a Lambda application where I'm using a layer to hold my dependencies but this makes things difficult when trying to run unit tests locally.

What I'm looking for is a way to keep my current architecture but run unit tests.

**Example structure**

```
dependencies
|---- nodejs
|----|---- node_modules
|----|---- package-lock.json
|----|---- package.json
src
|---- handler
|----|---- index.js
template.yml
buildspec.yml
```

**index.js**

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')  // Error: Cannot find module 'node-fetch'

exports.handler = async () => {
  const data = await fetch('https://someapi.com')
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(await data.json())
  }
}
```

As you can see from the folder structure, my dependencies are no longer where you would normally find them which causes an issue when trying to run unit tests or even simply calling my files from the terminal, `node index.js`.

What can I do to keep this structure, so layers work with AWS, but also run unit tests?

Comment: What are you using to unit test?

Comment: @gonzalon I would be using Jest